# Spark streaming (Spark 1.6) with CommitAsync API of Kafka 0.10

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

We need to use the `commitAsync` API of Kafka consumer. It's available with Kafka 0.9 and 0.10 version.

Can use Spark streaming 1.6 version with Kafka 0.10 ?

As per the blogs and sites I have read, Kafka 0.10 is only used/supported by spark streaming (Spark 2.1.X) version

Kafka Itself point in below link :
https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/06/offset-management-for-apache-kafka-with-apache-spark-streaming/

Comment: You misinterpreted the blogs, Spark 1.6 definitely works with Kafka 0.10. `commitAsync` API is only exposed in Spark 2.0, but there are other ways for your to manually store offsets.

Comment: Yes , there are other ways to save the offset. But  we are looking for CommitAsync to handle this so we do  not need to handle saving of offset externally. So just to confirm can we use commitAsync api with spark 1.6

Comment: It literally doesn't exist! Go to the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010/OffsetRange.scala) and search `commitAsync`. Then change branch to 1.6, repeat, see what happens